# LDAP users nested group membership in websphere

Tags: active-directory, ldap, websphere

IBM state that:

> **nested** 
>   Nested means that the response from the LDAP server to a
>   request for the group membership attribute already includes any nested
>   group relationships, but not any dynamic group memberships. If the
>   user is a member of group "A2" and "A2" is a member of group "A1",
>   then the list of group memberships includes both A1 and A2. This
>   information tells VMM that even if a client requests nested group
>   information, the response already provides it. No further work needs
>   to be done by VMM to satisfy the request.

How can I achieve this in websphere (connecting to Active Directory), so that if a user is a member of A2, and A2 is a member of group A1, I want the user to be in both A1 and A2.

I have nested groups enabled in the group attribute definition, however when I browse for the users, it only shows them belonging to group A2

Answer (score 1):

The configuration helps VMM only to know what is expected in the attribute returned from the LDAP server. VMM performs a fast lookup of the membership by using an attribute provided by the LDAP containing the membership. The  config element where you can define if it is nested, all or direct only helps VMM to have a hint if it needs to perform further actions.
All depends on the values returned from LDAP. In your case Active Directory. Usually it would be memberOf and from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> memberOf
>
> ```
> The memberOf attribute is a multi-valued attribute that contains groups of which the user is a direct member, except for the primary
> ```
>
> group, which is represented by the primaryGroupId. Group membership is
>   dependent on the domain controller (DC) from which this attribute is
>   retrieved:
>
> ```
>     At a DC for the domain that contains the user, memberOf for the user is complete with respect to membership for groups in that
> ```
>
> domain; however, memberOf does not contain the user's membership in
>   domain local and global groups in other domains.
>           At a GC server, memberOf for the user is complete with respect to all universal group memberships.
>
> ```
> If both conditions are true for the DC, both sets of data are contained in memberOf.
>
> Be aware that this attribute lists the groups that contain the user in their member attribute—it does not contain the recursive list
> ```
>
> of nested predecessors. For example, if user O is a member of group C
>   and group B and group B were nested in group A, the memberOf attribute
>   of user O would list group C and group B, but not group A.
>
> ```
> This attribute is not stored—it is a computed back-link attribute.
> ```

memberOf includes only the direct members. In combination with the configuration you have done VMM will only check the values inside of memberOf and does not perform any additional LDAP call.

Now I have too many options. Do you want to have the nested Groups for J2EE roles or within your application as you are calling VMM direct using API or or. I do not want to speculate to I leave it with the statement

memberOf returns the flat membership aka direct membership and VMM needs to perform additional calls to get the full info. By setting nested VMM will not perform any additional call

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch from `nested` to `direct`, to tell VMM to perform additional searches, since AD returns only direct members. See [Locating user group memberships in a Lightweight Directory Access Protocol registry](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_directindirectldap.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-2-1-1-2&lang=en) for more details.